# Twilio Sip Domain and Yealink phone tranfering does not work

Tags: twilio

Phone: Yealink T21 E2
Sip Using Twilio Sip Domain's

I make an inbound call to twilio, and it goes to the phone, I then transfer It call's the number I am transfering to, but when I click transfer again to complete the transfer, The Yealink gets a call and I am reconnected with the person I tried to transfer, and the person I tried to transfer the call to is left with dead air.

It is not an issue with the phone as the phone Transfer's just fine on the line that is attached to my asterisk server ( which I am hoping to replace with twilio )

Yealink Transfer's via SIP REFER,

From the Transfer section of there ui

```
"Call Transfer
The transfer parameters for administrator.Call transfer enables IP phones to transfer an existing call to another party. IP phones support call transfer using the REFER method specified in RFC 3515 and offer three types of transfer. "
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Programmable Voice SIP Domains do not currently support the SIP REFER method, so the transfer will fail. SIP REFER is only supported on the Elastic SIP Trunking product, designed for Trunking purposes.